# Get Latitude and Longitude of a road's kilometrical point with google geocoding

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I need to use geocoding to get the latitude and longitude of a kilo metrical point (milestone) in a road given the road's name and the number of kilometer.

Is there any way to do that? I being trying with google api with no luck and I have searched all the web. I don't need to use Google API's if there is another way.

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapQuest Open Platform Web Services. This is the link [click here](https://open.mapquestapi.com/)

And this is the sample code for [Reverse Geocoding sample](https://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reversesample)

Comment: Could you post an example? I'm trying to do it with a spanish road and it does not work. I don't know how should I refer the road and the kilometer